# Problems with Html.BeginForm() asp.net MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a SearchController.cs in my controller folder, it has an Action named Index. My search folder has a view named Index
The following code is in my /Controller/SearchController

```
    private TEAM2BooksDBEntities _db = new TEAM2BooksDBEntities();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string SearchFor)
    {
        var query = _db.Books.Where(em => em.title.Contains(SearchFor)).ToList();
        return View(query);
    }
```

The following code is in my /Home/Index

```
    <% using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Search")){ %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("SearchFor") %>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <% }%>
```

But no matter what I do when I hit the submit button it just reloads the current page. I want it to send the contents of the "SearchFor" box as a parameter to the Index action in the Search controller. How can I fix this?

Comment: How is your get method look like ? Also How you differentiate that your post method get called.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, I don't think I have a get method.

Comment: At first glance everything appears to be as it should. I'd try the following: (1) Do a View->Source on the Home/Index page and make sure the `<form>` element is correctly rendered; (2) Install Fiddler and see where it's posting the data and what it's posting for form values when you Submit; (3) Use the debugger to see if it's getting into your SearchController's `Index` action.

Comment: if your method don't get called that there should be exception. Problem is How you identify that Index is called or not.

Comment: Maybe you have a nested form? Like another form around this one? I've seen similar issues happen on this scenario. (nested forms are not valid)

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest try to use this.

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Search",FormMethod.Post)){ %>
<%= Html.TextBox("SearchFor") %>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% }%>
```

Comment: I added the FormMethod.Post but nothing

Comment: Post is default option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your action :

```
string SearchFor= Request.Form["SearchFor"];
```